# C compiler cannot create executables when trying to build Binutils

Tags: c, compilation, configure, binutils, linux-from-scratch

I am trying to build Linux From Scratch, and now I am at [chapter 5.4](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/binutils-pass1.html), which tells me how to build Binutils. I have binutils 2.20's source code, but when I try to build it:

```
time { ./binutils-2.20/configure --target=$LFS_TGT --prefix=/tools --disable-nls --disable-werror ; }
```

it gives me an error:

```
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-lfs-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for gcc... GCC
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/media/LFS':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

You can see my config.log at pastebin.com: http://pastebin.com/hX7v5KLn

I have just installed Ubuntu 10.04, and reinstalled GCC and installed G++. Also, the build is done by a non-root, non-admin user called 'lfs' (which is also described in Linux From Scratch), and on a different partition than where the system is installed.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you compile a simple c program from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/tools` directory didn't exist. I created it and now it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
```

before running configure.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the configure script is trying to use `GCC` as the compiler, but the compiler is actually called `gcc`.

Comment: Perhaps, but it is unlikely.  You need to find out why the configure script is trying to use "GCC" in the first place.  I suspect you have a borked build environment.